# smooth page transition in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm working on a flutter application. But the page transition is not smooth. And I can't find the problem to solve it;

The pages stop for a second before finished its transition

I'm using

```
import 'package:page_transition/page_transition.dart';

Navigator.push(context,  PageTransition(type: PageTransitionType.leftToRight, child: Service()));
```

But even before using this I have this problem

Can Anyone help me, please?

EDIT:
I'm using `shared_preferences` to save local data like user name and order data and so on.

My `initState()` usually reads userdata in each page to show it in the drawer

```
@override
void initState() {
  checkInternet();
  GetUserData();
  GetOrderData();
  super.initState();
}
```

Comment: Did you check transition in release mode or only in debug?

Comment: @AndreyTurkovsky release, debug even on profile the same problem

Comment: Could you share some more code of the pages?

Comment: @DominikR Done, If you can help me to ask about possibility and I'll post the code as I can't know post which code it's a big app.